# Is there a name for this design / pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I have a BoundingRectangle class, an Entity class and a World class.  When an Entity is created, if it's a solid object, it registers a class called CollisionData that contains a BoundingRectangle and a reference to the owner Entity with the World class.

ie:
`world.registerCollisionData(new CollisionData(this.boundingRectangle, this))`

Is there a name for what the CollisionData is?

Comment: It's probably closest to Composite Pattern or Dependency Injection, but what it really should be called is extremely high coupling and likely a violation of OO.

Comment: It's hard to tell in the absence of more information.  Do the collision data objects have methods that are invoked upon collision?  Or are they just dumb two-field objects dropped into a structure (world) optimized for fast collision lookup?

Comment: @drharris The "world" to which these collision data objects are registered is probably a kind of spatially indexed hash map mapping bounding boxes to objects.  It allows one to lookup bounding boxes locally and do other spatial queries in real-time.  Does it imply extremely high coupling?  Perhaps, but it might be warranted here. While we're used to seeing complex objects holding references to simple value objects, in this case we really do want to go "the other way."

Comment: How it works is that when a collision is detected, the world looks up the entity attached to the bounding box (via the CollisionData object) and notifies the entity of the collision.  Is this no good?

Comment: @Ray Toal that makes much more sense. In this use case, it is difficult to find a pure-OO way to accomplish this, but the current pattern seems acceptable to me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is separation of concerns and simple encapsulation rather than any specific pattern. So CollisionData just encapsulates information about bounding rectangle and an underlying Entity, in this way Entity is not aware of Bound Region directly.

EDIT:

Just found something the same see [ENCAPSULATED CONTEXT Pattern](http://www.allankelly.net/static/patterns/encapsulatecontext.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I think the pattern itself would be closest to [Mediator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern). Instead of an `Entity` communicating directly to another `Entity`, the World acts as the mediator between those `Entities`. `CollisionData` is then just an abstraction of obtaining the data you'd need to handle that situation.

You could obtain a more pure result by providing a method in `Entity` like:

```
public BoundingRectangle getBoundingRectangle();
```

And then, registering just the `Entity` with the `World` object:

```
world.registerEntity(this);
```

Then, the world simply uses `entity.getBoundingRectangle();` for its work. This is also similar to the [Registry Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html). Your current way is quite acceptable, this just may make a cleaner Sequence Diagram of what's going on (no proxy object needed to tie the two together), and it couples only two classes rather than three.

Comment: Yep but question is about CollisionData role

Answer (score 0):

It is called factory pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: I'm not so sure.  The OP asked if there is a name for what `CollisionData` is.  The `CollisionData` object was created with a simple constructor, not a factory method.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that CollisionData is either acting as a [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) or possibly part of a larger [composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Comment: Not feeling the love for the decorator or composite suggestion as there is no evidence that a `CollisionData` is an `Entity`.